# Make multiple webhook trigger configurations in Microsoft Flow Custom Connector

Tags: rest, api, webhooks, power-automate

I am creating a custom connector and would like to make 3 Webhook Triggers with different event payloads.
But the verb and path are same for all of them.

```
POST ->> "v1/Webhook"
```

So I am getting the error which says path and verb combination should be unique. 
I checked Githubs Triggers and saw that they have 3 Triggers and as per their documentation they have only one Webhook Url.
I would like to do the same for my service
[image]

I have already tried putting dynamic path parameters but it also gives the same error.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot use the payload to specify the event type. As a work around, you could instead use a different webhook url to distinguish between events.

Comment: Thanks @danspam. I ended up creating another endpoint which has eventType in the path.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try:

```
POST ->> "v1/Webhook#1"
POST ->> "v1/Webhook#2"
POST ->> "v1/Webhook#3"
```

Comment: Tried this. Not Working